# Stop Visual Studio from deploying SSRS report with domain account?

Tags: reporting-services

When trying to deploy report VS does not prompt me for my account credentials but instead attempts to use my domain windows credentials. How can I disable windows authentication for visual studio?

Answer (score 0):

I've used a service account to deploy reports before by:

Hold the shift key down and right click on the Visual Studio application in the menu. Select "More" | "Run as a different user".

[image]